# How to use Spring Transaction when using GenericApplicationContext

Tags: spring, spring-transactions, transactional, spring-annotations

When using Distributed Mysql Database, I've Created multiple dataSources, sessionFactory using BeanDefinitionBuilder
But transactional annotation doesn't seem to work when I execute Insert SQL 
using getBean('bean name') method below

( (SqlSessionTemplate)context.getBean('bean name') ).insert("xxxx",params)

Would you explain what I've missed?

```
Private GenericApplicationContext context = new GenericApplicationContext();

BeanDefinitionBuilder sessionFactoryBuilder = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.class);
sessionFactoryBuilder.addPropertyReference("dataSource", "dataSource" + beanName);
sessionFactoryBuilder.addPropertyValue("configLocation", "/sqlmap.xml");
context.registerBeanDefinition("sqlSessionFactory" + beanName, sessionFactoryBuilder.getBeanDefinition());

BeanDefinitionBuilder transactionManagerBuilder = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.class);
transactionManagerBuilder.addPropertyReference("dataSource", "dataSource" + beanName);
context.registerBeanDefinition("transactionManager",transactionManagerBuilder.getBeanDefinition());

ctx.refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add the following codes below and see if it works.

```
ConfigurableListableBeanFactory factory = context.getBeanFactory();
AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator aspectJPostProcessor = new AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator();
aspectJPostProcessor.setBeanFactory( factory );
aspectJPostProcessor.setProxyClassLoader( context.getClassLoader() );
factory.addBeanPostProcessor(aspectJPostProcessor);
```